# Three Classes, one Main, one for ArrayList, and one for print. how to make them work together?

Tags: java

newbie here! Here's the problem. I wanted to make a separate class for custom methods on an ArrayList for food items, and another separate class on a method to use just for printing the food items created in ArrayList, and I wanted to call them in the Main method. here's what I wrote in the "Foods" class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foods {
    
    ArrayList<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public void addFood(String input) {
        foods.add(input);
    }
    
    public void setFood(int number, String input) { 
        foods.set(number, input);
    }
    
    public void removeFood(int numebr) {
        foods.remove(numebr);
    }
    
    public void clearFood() {
        foods.clear();
    }
    
    public int sizeFood() {
        return foods.size();
    }
    
    public String getFood(int i) {
        return foods.get(i);
    }

}
```

here's the "Print" class:

```
public class Print {
    
    public void printFoods() {
        
        Foods foods = new Foods();
        
        for (int i=0; i<foods.sizeFood(); i++)
            System.out.println(foods.getFood(i));
    }

}
```

and here's Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foods foods = new Foods();
        Print print = new Print();
        
        foods.addFood("Beer");
        foods.addFood("Tequila");
        
        print.printFoods();
        
    }
}
```

and the result is Blank!

So to my understanding, I'm making two instances of "Foods" class, one in the Main class and another in Print class, and that's why when I call the print method I get blank result. so I tried to convert "Print" class to Static so It might see the initialization of Foods class in the Main class and therefore I could remove the instance of Foods class created in Print class. but since converting Print class to Static wasn't allowed, I'm stuck!

I would really appreciate it if you guys could suggest a work around this issue. and one thing to mention, moving the print method to the Main class is a no go, cause I really want to keep different functions organized and separated from the main class.  thanks

Comment: Add a `Foods foods` parameter to `printFoods`.

Comment: Thanks man, problem solved! cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new object. Try this:

```
public class Print {
    
    public void printFoods(Foods foods) {
                  
        for (int i=0; i<foods.sizeFood(); i++)
            System.out.println(foods.getFood(i));
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foods foods = new Foods();
        Print print = new Print();
        
        foods.addFood("Beer");
        foods.addFood("Tequila");
        
        print.printFoods(foods);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is that the `Print` class has its own instance of `Foods` so it doesn't matter what you add to the instance defined in `Main`.  I would argue that the behavior you have implemented in the  `Print` class should be moved to the `Foods` class.

```
public class Foods {
  ... the other stuff ...
  public void printFoods() {
    for (String food : foods) {
      System.out.println(food);
    }
  }
}
```

Then usage becomes...

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foods foods = new Foods();
    foods.addFood("Beer");
    foods.addFood("Tequila");
    foods.printFoods();
  }
}
```

Comment: Extra credit for thinking outside the box!

Comment: That's a very good point, but the thing is I was going for a very organized categorization, so should I ever want to extend on this I'd be able to dedicate one class just for all the printings of the whole projects. for example if I add a class for "Cars" I'd be able to use "Print" Class to print arrays in Car class. I don't know if I'm making any sense or not.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you always print a new list instead of the one created externally. As @luk2302 said in the comments section, offer the list created externally to the printFoods() method and remove the `Foods foods = new Foods();` from inside the method.

As an example:
`print.printFoods(foods);`

```
public void printFoods(Foods foods) {
        
        // Foods foods = new Foods(); // remove it
        
        for (int i=0; i<foods.sizeFood(); i++)
            System.out.println(foods.getFood(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Foods` in your `Print` class is different from `Foods` in main method.

As suggested by @luk2302, you can add a parameter to your `printFoods` method like this:

```java
public class Print {
    public void printFoods(Foods foods) {
        for (int i=0; i<foods.sizeFood(); i++)
            System.out.println(foods.getFood(i));
    }
}
```

And call the `printFoods` with the `foods` as argument:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foods foods = new Foods();
        Print print = new Print();
        
        foods.addFood("Beer");
        foods.addFood("Tequila");
        
        // Pass the foods object in printFoods method
        print.printFoods(foods);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for a through explanation, cheers mate